# Is there equivalent for "I'm starving to death" in Spanish?

Tags: modismos

In English the sentence "I'm starving to death" in the meaning of "I'm very hungry" (rather than of a real pathological condition). Is there an equivalent in Spanish?

Comment: You just asked that in Portuguese, right?

Answer (score 3):

A free online translator, like [DeepL Translate](https://www.deepl.com) gives you an immediate answer:

- **Me muero de hambre**

and a couple of variations:

- **Me estoy muriendo de hambre**
- **Estoy muerto de hambre**